# Best unit testing framework for old school QNX?

Tags: c, unit-testing, unix, qnx

I'm working on an old variant of unix (qnx 4.x to be exact). I'm trying to shoe-horn in modern software methodologies atop 20+ year old technology. In short I need a unit testing framework for QNX.

Keep in mind we've got a bare bones C compiler and that's pretty much it. Anyone got any suggestions on how I can unit test this beast?

Answer (score 3):

[CuTest](http://cutest.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) it's the most powerful C++ testing framework. Also you can use [Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) with it for your mocking needs.

Comment: Hopefully they've already solved their problem, but even if they hadn't over the past 2.5 years, that's C++, whereas OP has C.

Answer (score -3):

```
bool doTest(int(*myFunc)(int))
{
  printf("Testing...\n");
  printf("...testing complete.\n");
  printf("Test passed!\n");
}
```

Comment: -1. Eviljack only has a C compiler, so there's no bool.

Comment: @MaxVT bare bones C has `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: @ColeJohnson Modern C has stdbool.h (part of C99). The OP uses "20+ year old technology" so I would not assume C99 is supported in this case.

Comment: @MaxVT 20 year old technology != 20 year old compiler. I have a computer 8 years old that runs the latest version on gcc